# UnityからスクリーンキャプチャでiOSのカメラロールに保存する方法

Tags: ios, c#, unity3d

Unity(C#)で画面のスクリーンキャプチャーを取り、 
iOSのカメラロール(写真を保存している場所)に保存させたいのですが、 
方法がわかりません。

スクリーンキャプチャーの取り方は、 
Application.CaptureScreenshot 
で出来ると思うのですが、 
アプリのデータ領域に画像が保存されるだけで、 
ユーザーが、その画像を閲覧できるようにはならないらしいです。

以下のサイトなどを参考にしましたが、Xcodeの知識が無いため理解が難しかったです。 
[Unityでスクリーンショットを撮影し、iPhoneのカメラロールに保存する方法。](http://yuseinishiyama.com/posts/2013/09/06/screenshot-with-unity-ios/)

どなたか方法、または解説だけでもいいので、ご教授いただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 参考サイトがリンク切れしているようですが。

Answer (score 1):

iOSの機能を使うにはどうしても iOS＋Xcodeの知識が必要になります。

Unity は AssetStore で「機能」を買う事もできるので、ちょっと宣伝になってしまいますが私が作ったプラグイン（＝アセット）を紹介しておきます。

iOS Load Texture From PhotoLibrary/Camera  ($10)
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/9083

元々はカメラロールにある画像やカメラで撮影した写真を Unityのテクスチャとして使えるようにするプラグインだったのですが、多く要望があったので保存する機能もつけました。これを使えば簡単にスクリプトから任意の画像やスクリーンショットを保存することができますので、ご検討ください。